# Importance of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee

I know that threads are key members of a software/web application.
But I didn't use them during my college project which was about online shopping using Java EE technology.

Can someone tell me how they can be useful if I had applied them in my project?

I am familiar with cuncurrency etc but just want a big picture to understand their imoprtance.
For example why should I bother to put some code in threads (apart from the fact of multiple requests and I should bother ). Just a bit confused.

Comment: This is something you should research, not ask a vague question about. A Google search will help you out.

Comment: @JesseJ: I actually don't have a problem with this question.  It's a real question that professionals do face - why would I use threads vs. why wouldn't I use threads, or when to use them and when not to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've done a Java EE project, then threads are something you would not likely have touched. When using Java EE, you're coding parts that will be plugged in to some container. For example, you code the EJBs and the application server takes care of caching these and calling them. You code persistence entities and the application server will provide you with a persistence context and takes care of transactions...
An application server will have a number of threads pooled to take care of client requests. They're all managed for you, so you don't really get to see it. Because you're coding against a framework.

Switch to Java SE and things are different. If you're building an application mostly from the ground up, maybe using some libraries but not really a framework, chances are that in a non-trivial application you'll require multi-threading. Although knowing how or when to use concurrency in the best possible way is something you learn through study and experience (the book "Java concurrency in practice" is sort of the go-to work here), you could basically say that any time something needs to be done in the background while other work is also performed, or your program can continue without having to wait on some call to return, multi-threading can come into play.

Answer (score 1):

Since you were using Java EE, it is already a multi threaded environment that's why you didn't fell the need for multi threading.

You must be knowing that the for each request that comes to your servlet, each request is handled in a seperate thread by the container. So on the background you were using multi threading provided by the container.

I don't know whether the example that now I am going to give relates to any pratical scenario or not but it is just for understanding:

Say for the new year, you need to send an email to all your registered users about the new year offers on your shopping website. So there may thousands or may be more customer in your database. So you can use threads here that will perform the task of sending emails in some chunks say for 1000 customers, you may use 10 threads each of which sends email to 100 customers. NOTE: This is just a scenario that came to my mind.

Comment: Thanks Abu for your reply.Though question came to my mind is why should I sent mail in chunks, moreover separate ten threads.ItI can send in one go!

Comment: @ashu I wrote that I don't know whether the example fits correctly or not.

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on the context.  If you're writing Java chances are you're on the server.  If so, your application server typically manages threads.

Client-side Java code is rare these days but still exists.  Threads in Swing, for example, are important for background tasks so that the repaint/event thread isn't held up.

It's probably more important to understand the concept of thread safety than "when to use threads".  Joshua Bloch's Effective Java is a great book for that (or was, many years ago when I read it).

Comment: Thabks for your reply john

Answer (score 0):

## Why would you use threads?

(Keep in mind, this is independent of any platform suite you elect to use.)

### Performance

Imagine, if you will, you're going shopping, and you don't have a lot of things in your basket.  There's about ten other people going shopping in front of you, and many of them have a lot more things in their baskets.  It will take a lot longer to process you, when you don't have nearly as much stuff that the checkout lanes have to deal with, as opposed to opening another lane.

Threads are similar to checkout lanes in a store.  The more of them you have, the more operations you can perform.

As computers stop getting faster and faster, and are more focused on putting more cores onto the chip, we as software engineers have to come up with ways to make our algorithms and applications more efficient to suit the use of our hardware.  Multithreading is one way.  We can design and implement algorithms to take a large problem and divide it into smaller sub-problems, to be recombined later.

## Why *wouldn't* you use threads?

### Single Core Systems

There's an overhead to threading, which is in the context switching and spinup of the lightweight process.  If you've only got one core, you'll be spending more time dealing with the overhead instead of processing any actual data.

### Too many threads is a bad thing

I've shared my analogy of the checkout lanes, and while having more of them open is in general good, if there's not enough work to give all of them to justify having them open, then they're wasted resources and clock cycles.  It's *critical* to balance the amount of work you have to do to the number of threads you need.

Comment: Single core? Unless all those threads are just waiting on some outside resource like a database or mail server or web service.

Comment: Threads are much lighter in weight than multiple processes. Context switching on processor level is significant for processes but much less so for threading. While multi-core processors can be more efficient in threaded execution, even single-core systems tend to have explicit threading support and optimizations. You'd need to find a very basic processor to make thread-management overhead exceed the performance gain.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a system that received a request (just an HTTP post) to process a list of data. For each bit of data, it needed to call another system and wait 1-6 seconds for the response. 1000 bits of data would take a tens of minutes to process. The HTTP connection would time out. So I used concurrency to issue 20 or 30 requests at a time to the remote system. My system was mostly just waiting anyway. That cut the total processing time to 3 to 5 percent of before and everybody was happy.

Now, be warned that it is not legal to use Java SE concurrency features inside a Java EE container. The container is doing all sorts of multi-threading and your multi-threading would or could interfere. We found that what we were doing worked ok though we broke the rule. In other situations, I have tried it and found it not to work.

If you are using WebSphere or Weblogic Java EE containers, they both have a proprietary frameworks to handle multi-threading. Its the same one and was a proposed standard, but the name eludes me today.

If you are using a servlet container like Tomcat, you can use Java SE multi-threading.

The Spring Framework has some utility classes that you can program to for some concurrency needs. These make it easy to switch the backing concurrency from Java SE to the frameworks used by IBM and Oracle.

Comment: CommonJ. Thought of the name. There is also an open source implementation of it.